# Genus of Covering Space of 3-Manifold

Tags: 3-manifolds, covering-spaces

Let $M_g$ and $M_h$ be closed orientable 3-manifolds of genus $g$ and $h$ respectively and suppose that $M_g$ is an $n$-sheeted cover of $M_h$. Is there a formula that would allow us to compute $g$ if we knew the values of $h$ and $n$?

I know there is a formula for closed orientable surfaces and I was wondering if there was a result for $3$-manifolds.

Comment: What's the genus of a $3$-manifold?

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev Heegaard genus

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/86800/heegaard-splitting-of-covering-hyperbolic-manifold?rq=1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heegaard genus is not very constructive and is very difficult to control. Obviously, there cannot be a formula in terms of just $n$ and $h$. It suffices to consider the double coverings $S^3\to\Bbb R\mathrm{p}^3$ and $S^1\times S^2\to S^1\times S^2$.

Comment: There is no formula, but there might be a bound.